# Terraform: The value only to the first resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I've 3 `sqs endpoints`, and I'm trying to use a value to the first created resource, however the value associating with other 2 resources as well.

My resource is `aws_vpc_endpoint` it has been created with `for_each` expression, one of attributes is `private_dns_enabled` which is bool, and it must be applied only to the first created resource, other created resources must be ignored

How can I associate the value only to the first created resource, otherwise its conflicting with error:

```
Error creating VPC Endpoint: InvalidParameter: private-dns-enabled cannot be set because there is already a conflicting DNS domain for sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com in the VPC
```

Maybe there is a function or patters, for my specific question

`sqs.tf`

```
... truncated ...

private_dns_enabled = lookup(var.parameters[0].sqs[0], "private_dns", false)

... truncated ...
```

P.S. If set to `false` there is no problem, right now only 1 SQS Endpoint is created other 2 are failed

Comment: Can you provide complete reproducible example of what you are doing and trying to achieve?